# How can $n$ identical objects be distributed $r$ persons vs. $r$ groups such that each gets at least $1$ object How is this different?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Does dividing in groups mean that **order is not important** (but groups can be different as well)? Also if the objects are distinct won't the order matter if the distribution is for a group as well?

How do we come to know from the question if all the objects are to be completely distributed? i.e. $100$ pens to $5$ people so $10$ pens each should also be a valid distribution even though $50$ are left

Comment: Possibly the difference is that people are considered distinct individuals while "groups" are interchangeable (indistinguishable).  The subject is sometimes expressed as ordered vs. unordered partitions.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, order is not important-if there are are two groups of 11 players each, it does not matter what is the ordering of the players...we just need to know the grouping.

For your second question, we have to distribute the items completely. You can't say "I distributed 1000$ among the poor people sitting there" even though you gave no one nothing.

These are general conventions.